# How do I cheat super mario html 5 to give me infinite lives and fire flowers?

Tags: cheats, super-mario-html5

I have been playing the emulation of Super Mario in Firefox, and I was trying to find out how to give me infinite lives or fireflowers. I have a very lightweight computer and I don't want to download anything, so is there a way to use dev console or edit the html? I am not good with coding but would like to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Press F12

in the console type : `data` and press enter. You'll see most of the variables there.

For the number of lives for instance, type : `data.lives.amount = 99` then when you lose or gain a life your screen will get updated and you'll have those 99 (+-1) lives

Comment: Also I see that there is a command that is killgoomba or killothercharacters, how do I use that command?

Comment: Just type killOtherCharacters() and everything else will die.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your character and environment variables using the console by pressing `F12`. Type your desired cheat code into the console and press Enter.

Here are the functions you have asked about:

Infinite lives (technically a high number):
`setLives(999);`

or make yourself Invincible:
`mario.star = true`

Fire Flowers:
`marioShroom(mario)`

Kill all characters except Mario:
`killOtherCharacters()`

Comment: is there a way to have the console give me a shroom or kill other characters every second?

Comment: @Tnings Sure, just add a loop `while(data.time.amount>0) {killOtherCharacters()}`

Comment: when I do this it freezes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Tnings Try `setTimeout(function() {killOtherCharacters() },1000);`

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working, sorry.

Comment: @Tnings Go to StackOverflow and ask them how to write a while loop for js. I'm not on my computer now so I can't test.

Comment: This should do it: `window.setInterval(function(){ killOtherCharacters()},1000);`